# Do I need a comma in this example?

Tags: django, django-forms

This code is a little dense for me so I just want to figure out if I missed a comma in between label=_("Email") and label.  This current example is giving me invalid syntax error.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-trigger':'keyup', 'data-required' : 'true'}), max_length=75, label=_("Email"))
    label=_("Email"))
```

Comment: bracket matching text editors can be of immense help when writing code.

Comment: You don't need to specify email twice anyway. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Indenting the code and rearranging keyword arguments helps to improve readability and see that there is an extra `label=_("Email"))` you need to remove:

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75, 
                         label=_("Email"),
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-trigger': 'keyup', 
                                                       'data-required': 'true'}))
```